# Package-deal or plain ticket + hotel booked separately?

Tags: tickets, money, hotels, bookings

I am looking to go to Curaçao for my honeymoon next year and I am curious if it would be cheaper to buy a plain ticket and book my desired hotel seperately or book a packagedeal from a travel-agency.

What things do I have to keep in mind if booking the hotel and ticket seperately comes in cheaper? Stuff like transport to your hotel is mostly included when you book with an agency.

Comment: booking the hotel on the date you are actually arriving at your destination? Honestly, package-deal only are sometimes good deals, imho, but there is nothing specific to know about it. Unless you want to narrow your question to something more precise.

Comment: Which country would you be booking in? In some counties (eg the UK with [ATOL](http://www.packpeaceofmind.co.uk/)), booking a package deal of flight+hotel gets you extra protections beyond that of two individual bookings

Comment: @Vince But the question is about booking directly (e.g. is there some issues with insurance, assistance if something is wrong, etc.)

Comment: @Relaxed OK I didn't know it included anything else than a hotel and a flight. This is not very obvious in the question.

Comment: @Gagravarr I live in the Netherlands.

Comment: @Vince Package don't necessarily specifically include that but you have a contract with a local company, bound by consumer protection laws like the one Gagravarr mentioned, which is not the case if you phone some hotel in another country. In any case, the question was not “What if I book a package?” but “What if book hotels and tickets separately?”

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times, booking separately will be cheaper (the travel agency has to make its profit) but it is not a definite rule: they can sometimes negotiate discounts and get better prices; just compare the prices...

Comment: package deals can often be cheaper because the travel agency can buy in bulk, thus offering you a lower price than booking yourself AND making a profit.